# Getting "MongoError: $or must be an array" even though it's given two expressions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is for a map such that a search for "fullName" will return all documents with either the input as their fullName or an alternateName. Both queries work individually, but when put together in an $or operator, it says that $or requires an array. This only happens when a $not operator is also added.

I think that when the search is marked as negative and the $not operator is applied, it interprets one of the expressions as `null` and so it doesn't read as an array?

part of searchMap object:

```
fullName: (d, exact) => ({
        $or: [
            { fullName: getRegExp(d, exact) },
            { alternateNames: { $elemMatch: { alternateName: getRegExp(d, exact) } } },
        ]
    }),
```

This only occurs when we have marked the search as "negative":

```
if (queryItem.negative === true && queryItem._id !== "entry") {
                        for (let key in item) {
                            item[key] = { $not: item[key] };
                        }
                    }
...
```

Ideally, a negative search will return all documents that have the input as neither the fullName or the alternateName.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred when item[key] was an array. Fixed by changing the key from $or to $nor.